# Define a Decryption algorithm on a given group-based Cramer Shoup lite scheme

Tags: public-key, chosen-plaintext-attack, group-theory, hardness-assumptions

I am currently working on public key encryption schemes and I want some help to figure out how decryption algorithms work. Suppose we have a public key $pk = (G,p,g,e)$ with $e \in Z^*_p$ . (where $G$ is the message space, $g$ is a generator of $G$, $p$ is the prime order of the cyclic group $G$). The secret key $sk = d$ where $d \in Z_p$ such that $ed = 1\bmod p$ (similar to Cramer-Shoup). Now Suppose that the encryption algorithm given the pk and a message $m \in G$ and a arbitrary picked group element $h←G$ is defined as $E_pk(m,h)=(u,v)=(m^eh,h^e)$.

I am trying to find an efficient decryption algorithm (using the same secret key sk). Can this scheme be IND-CPA secure. I tried to reduce this problem to a cryptographic assumption (e.g. a computentional hard problem) but I did not manage to. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Eventually, the above scheme is similar to Cramer-Shoup (lite version). Any idea of finding an efficient decryption algorithm? The scheme is not secure.

Comment: I'm confused. I don't think this scheme offers any meaningful security at all. To see this note that an adversary knows both $e$ and $p$ and can thus compute $d$ (the private key!) themselves. As for decryption, try doing what RSA does to recover $h$ and remove it from the first entry of the pair.

Comment: Maybe you are right that it is not IND-CPA secure. Thus, I have to think about an attack to this scheme (as you described). What do you mean by "remove it from the first entry of the pair"?

Comment: It is certain that this scheme is insecure because an adversary can just compute the private key from the public key the same way as the legitimate user. As for decryption you want to get $m^e$ (then "RSA-decryption") from $m^eh$ which you can be first obtaining $h$ from $h^e$.

Comment: Sorry again for that, I am a bit confused. Can you give me a more detailed description/sketch/example of such attack?

Comment: "$ed \equiv 1\bmod p$" - do you rather mean $ed \equiv 1 \pmod{p-1}$ or $ed \equiv 1 \pmod{ \phi(p) }$.  As written, the decryptor would be better off ignoring $d$, and computing the decryption using $e^{-1} \pmod{\phi(p) }$

Comment: As i said above, I am not sure that this scheme is secure. Yes, I am sure that $ed = 1modp$. I am trying to find an attack on this scheme.